# How to install firmware

Tags: firmware

I having problems with wifi. I find the firmware. It is .tgz but I don't know how to install it. My wifi card is `Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)`
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What WiFi card do you have? Chances are there's an easier install method than compiling and installing from the source.

Comment: Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)

Comment: That should work fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: No driver needed.

Comment: so what's the problem I disconnected from wifi after using for couple of minutes. Do you mean my wifi card is updated

Comment: AFAIK that's some other problem. Try rebooting your router.

Comment: I can't access router.

Comment: Unplug the router and plug it back in.

Comment: 1. in general you do not need to install software for your wifi. 2. impossible to answer this without context. We need make and model of wifi. We need a link to the download. edit: Inter wireless works out of the box. Please reconsider this topic and focus on the PROBLEM not on what you believe is an answer to a problem

Comment: I just need the answer of this. I asked couple of times about this problem in different forums but no one answered that question. So I decided find the solution piece by piece

Comment: Where did you find the firmware, and what is the result of [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/178596)?

Answer (score 1):

This link: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi includes information regarding the download and installation for Intel HW.

According to that link, installation is simple and done by: `cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware`.
I recommend you read it first.

Generally speaking, for a tarball included `.tgz` file, which is essentially an archive (like RAR, ZIP etc), you may use the following:

1. Using GUI go to the folder you've downloaded it in, and right click your mouse to select 'extract here'.
2. Then using CLI (the terminal), go to the directory in which it was
   extracted (`cd [directory]`) and input `./configure`, `make` and 
   `make install` - in that order.

Comment: @steeldriver you are right. My advice was based on personal experience with Intel, nothing more. Let me try and fix this.